# ExpandableListView with JSON in android - Listing Error

Tags: android, json, expandablelistview

Trying to make ExpandableListView with JSON parsing Getting error,

i Just tryed to parse the data from JSON to a single child group, but failed. Anyone resolve it and it will be helpful for me. Help will be appreciated.

Project contains No error but force closed by emulator after deploy.

### My code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

    JSONArray contacts = null;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    String [] str=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new DownloadJSON().execute();

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                        childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Sharani Designs");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override   
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {
                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                        .getJSONfromURL("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/");

                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
                    for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        str[i]=c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);
                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                        String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                        String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                        String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                        map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        contactList.add(map);
                    }
            }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml

            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int x=0;x<str.length;x++)
        {
            top250.add(str[x]);
        }

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
        nowShowing.add("Turbo");
        nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");
        nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }



}
```

Added Internet Permission,
Having the JSONfunctions class in my project package,
JSON file is also a valid one.

i think in this part only the logical error is happening but dont know how to solve it,

```
for(int x=0;x<str.length;x++)
{
     top250.add(str[x]);
}
```

### updated Logcat after initialized str variable

```
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490): Process: info.androidhive.expandablelistview, PID: 2490
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.expandablelistview/info.androidhive.expandablelistview.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at info.androidhive.expandablelistview.MainActivity.prepareListData(MainActivity.java:208)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at info.androidhive.expandablelistview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
02-07 06:47:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(2490):     ... 11 more
02-07 06:47:06.511: D/dalvikvm(2490): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 201K, 9% free 2984K/3260K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
02-07 06:47:08.771: I/Process(2490): Sending signal. PID: 2490 SIG: 9
```

Comment: what is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: Forceclosed by emulator

Comment: Add logcat log please :)

Comment: at which line you got NPE?

Comment: @PiyushGupta I think that this is the line: `nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");` but I see no error in there.

Comment: in prepareListData funtion from top250 for loop. @PiyushGupta

Comment: you have not initialized your **str** array thats why

Comment: i initialized with "null" now and again its getting force closed. @PiyushGupta

Comment: Maybe after that change your force close reason is different, you have to check logcat always to see where exactly the problem is.

Comment: i updated the logcat now, do a watch @zozelfelfo

Comment: just add `if(str != null)` before `for(int x=0;x<str.length;x++)`.

Comment: initializing str with null will not work. you will need to initialize it to some value then only the str.length loop will work else it will never get into it , if str is set to null and the condition @zozelfelfo suggests

Comment: Added and getting the same result, i think the str variable is not update with any value from json parsing, logcat showing NUllPointerException. @zozelfelfo

Comment: Can anyone suggest me the tutorial for the same, i need to populate json data into ExpandableListview.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably is that you are populating your `ExpandableListView` before your JSON Data is available. Try to call your `prepareListData` function in your `onPostExecute`function.

Probably this will take a while and you will have your `ExpandableListView`empty, if after doing so you dont get your expandablelistview filled try to call to `expListView.invalidateViews`

Another problem I see is that you dont have initialized your `str` attribute, this is probably the reason of your NPE.

Comment: Json data is invoked with DownloadJSON funtion before the prepareListData executes, so JSON data is available but the parsed data is not populating to the child list of Expandablelistview. @zozelfelfo

Comment: This is where you are wrong, you are launching a AsyncTask, this works in ANOTHER thread, your UI Thread can finish its function before your AsyncTask starts. Add a log in your `doInBackground` function and check it.

Comment: so edit it in my code where i done wrong, @zozelfelfo

Answer (score 0):

in your code above you have the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
    str[i]=c.getString(TAG_NAME);
    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
    String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);
```

I failed to notice where exactly you have initialized the str array with some space meaning like this:

```
str[] = new String[100]; // for example
```

if possible try initializing this to some value and then store the value into the array.

And an array size cannot be increased or reduced later on, it would be nice if you use an `arraylist` instead.

Also, even in the `prepareList()` method, you are accessing the length of the string, when it is not initialized to some value as mentioned some lines here above.

Comment: how to initialized with dynamic value? here your example code contains 100.

Comment: it was just an example. since it is not possible to predefine the size of the array from before hand, use an array list. where you simply have to add the items to the array list.

Comment: ya correct, but array list for other two child list has been added manually, the first arraylist i created and the value for tat i am getting from tat str variable.

Comment: If your str is dynamic use an `ArrayList<String>`